# Distinct in Ienumerable model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

I have a `IEnumerable` ViewModel. This has the same names and I want to select only one name and display it in the header. Please suggest.

My code is a below. I am trying to use distinct but it does not work

```
@foreach (var item in Model.abc)
{
    {
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:100px" >@Html.Label("Name")</td>
            <td style="width:225px"> @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.Name.Distinct())</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

To be more specific: my result will have only names `{a,a,a,a,a}` so I just want to pick the single `{a}` and display it.

Comment: What if Distinct returns multiple results? Which one do you want to display in the header?

Comment: There are many names that is the same value. I need the distinct name.

Comment: But if in your model you have the following names for example `{Foo, Foo, Bar, Bar, Baz}` the result of Distinct would be `{Foo, Bar, Baz}`. So I repeat my question once again: `What if Distinct returns multiple results? Which one do you want to display in the header?` Do you know what does the `Distinct` extension method do and what does it return?

Comment: To answer your question... all the names are the same {foo,foo,foo,foo} and  i would want to display foo only once

Comment: What's the point of ending up with a collection containing all the same values? Why not filter them in the controller action and then adapt your view model accordingly?

Comment: I need to display these values in the grid. THis is a collection of other values as well but need only one name to be displayed in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This has the same names and i want to select only one name and display
>   it in the header.

If they all are the same and assuming `Name` implements `IEnumerable` you could try [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx):

**Update**: add a new property to your model

```
otherProperty = item.Name.First();
```

Then:

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.otherProperty)
```

Comment: This won't work. You cannot pass such lambda expression to HTML helpers. They simply won't understand it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, you are right. I updated my answer which involves adding a new property to the model

Comment: Yes, that might be a solution except that we still don't know what the OP is trying to achieve. He talked about the Distinct method which doesn't fit with his description. So hopefully he will update his question and be more specific so that your answer could be the one that actually fits best.

Comment: i am not sure where i should be adding the property

Comment: To the object that holds the enumeration. If Model.abc is the enumeration then add it to Model.

Answer (score 0):

**use this code in your app**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => x.Title).Distinct())
 {
 <option>@item</option>
}
```

> you can use `@html.display(X=>item)` instead `@item`